# Maven + tomcat7-plugin + JBehave + WireMock

Tags: maven, plugins, tomcat7, wiremock

I'm using Maven and JBehave for integration test. I'm using the tomcat7 maven plugin as well that start running before the integration run so that I can write jBehave stories that hit my api.

I'm now trying now include Wiremock because I have some external HTTP calls thatI would like to mock, wiremock seems like the perfect solution.

I'd prefer not to write any mock stub in java and I saw on the Wiremock doc that there is a standalone mode where you simply put your files and mapping in a folder I wire mock will pick them up when necessary.

I have included this in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
      <version>1.57</version>
      <classifier>standalone</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

but when I run the integration test I get this

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext"
```

the embedded tomcat7 fails to run. Could someone help me setting up wire mock in standalone mode with maven?

Comment: The error java.lang.LinkageError comes in a situation when there are two classloaders involved in loading a class. I came across this issue before in spring

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest trying the 2.0.4-beta version?

For one thing wiremock-standalone has its own POM, which avoids having to explicitly exclude transitive dependencies. It also uses the latest Servlet API, reducing the risk of this clashing with your container.